# How to develop Custom Gradle Plugin with Java

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I am attempting to develop a custom Gradle plugin using Java (and NOT Groovy).

I am using this Groovy plugin as a guide

```
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        def hasApp = project.plugins.withType(AppPlugin)
        def hasLib = project.plugins.withType(LibraryPlugin)
        if (!hasApp && !hasLib) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("'android' or 'android-library' plugin required.")
        }

        final def log = project.logger
        final def variants
        if (hasApp) {
            variants = project.android.applicationVariants
        } else {
            variants = project.android.libraryVariants
        }

        project.dependencies {
            debugCompile 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT'
            // TODO this should come transitively
            debugCompile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.6'
            compile 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.2-SNAPSHOT'
        }

        project.extensions.create('hugo', HugoExtension)

        variants.all { variant ->
            if (!variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
                log.debug("Skipping non-debuggable build type '${variant.buildType.name}'.")
                return;
            } else if (!project.hugo.enabled) {
                log.debug("Hugo is not disabled.")
                return;
            }

            JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompile
            javaCompile.doLast {
                String[] args = [
                        "-showWeaveInfo",
                        "-1.5",
                        "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                        "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                        "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                        "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                        "-bootclasspath", project.android.bootClasspath.join(File.pathSeparator)
                ]
                log.debug "ajc args: " + Arrays.toString(args)

                MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
                new Main().run(args, handler);
                for (IMessage message : handler.getMessages(null, true)) {
                    switch (message.getKind()) {
                        case IMessage.ABORT:
                        case IMessage.ERROR:
                        case IMessage.FAIL:
                            log.error message.message, message.thrown
                            break;
                        case IMessage.WARNING:
                            log.warn message.message, message.thrown
                            break;
                        case IMessage.INFO:
                            log.info message.message, message.thrown
                            break;
                        case IMessage.DEBUG:
                            log.debug message.message, message.thrown
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have developed this for checking Android App / Android Library

```
 final PluginCollection hasAndroidAppPlugin = project.getPlugins().withType(AppPlugin.class);
        final PluginCollection hasAndroidLibraryPlugin = project.getPlugins().withType(LibraryPlugin.class);
        if (hasAndroidAppPlugin.isEmpty() & hasAndroidLibraryPlugin.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("'android' or 'android-library' plugin required.");
        }
```

and this for setting my dependencies

```
final DependencyHandler dependencyHandler = project.getDependencies();
        dependencyHandler.add("debugCompile", "com.example.perspective:perspective-runtime:0.0.1");
        dependencyHandler.add("debugCompile", "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.10.3");
```

How can I achieve the following using Java?

I am stuck trying to identify "Variants" e.g. applicationVariants/libraryVariants.

```
if (hasApp) {
            variants = project.android.applicationVariants
        } else {
            variants = project.android.libraryVariants
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried project.android.getApplicationVariants()

Comment: when I try this "final Object obj = project.android.getApplicationVariants();" my IDE doesnt like "android" it says it cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Try `project.getAndroid().getApplicationVariants()`

Comment: @SimonSchiller, using "project.getAndroid().getApplicationVariants()" gives cannot resolve method "getAndroid()"

Comment: I was just guessing, however I think Lance provided a working solution.

Comment: @SimonSchiller, thanks for taking the time to respond, Lance has indeed got me moving forward, although Im now stuck attempting to discover "javaCompile.destinationDir" Im guessing these are properties though

Comment: javaCompile will come from `getProject().getTasks().getByName("javaCompile")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm familiar with Gradle, NOT Android

I'm guessing that the `android` property is an extension object. See [plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build) and [ExtensionContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/ExtensionContainer.html)

If you put this println into an android build

```
println "${project.android.class.name}"
```

you'll see what type the extension object is. Then you can do

```
AndroidModel aModel = getProject().getExtensions().getByType(AndroidModel.class)
```

I'm using `AndroidModel` here, you'll replace that with whatever was printed in the println above

You could also do

```
Object aModel = getProject().getExtensions().getByName("android");
System.out.println(aModel.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: The println give "com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated", from that I used "import com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension;" and AppExtension allows me to call final Object obj = appExtension.getApplicationVariants();